# I ran minecraft.exe on wine and a black screen popped up

Tags: wine, minecraft, floppy

I ran minecraft.exe on my floppy with wine and a black window popped up.
I saw log-in but it all was black you could only see the borders of login.
how can i fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use wine ?, when you could just use linux . But first you need to install Java and make sure that all your graphics drivers are installed

Comment: If his graphics drivers were not installed, running in wine would not help him either!

Comment: i wanted to see what's the difffents

Answer (score 1):

Run minecraft in Linux instead.  You will need a version of Java, OpenJDK7 works well, or you could go to the trouble of installing Java 8.